# Выход за границы массива в программе

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, циклы

**Задача**. Дано 3 числа : `a, b, c` и одномерный массив. Заполнить его следующим образом: `a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c ...`

**Решение**

```
void FillArray(int cnt, double *arr, double a = 0, double b = 1, double c = 2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i+=3) {
        arr[i] = a;
        arr[i + 1] = b;
        arr[i + 2] = c;
    }
}
```

В моем решении есть выход за границы массива. Как это исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Harry, верно, я слышком коротко хотел ответить как не выходить за пределы:) Убрал коммент

Comment: Судя по количеству ответов, я был прав, написав **Вариантов масса** :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вариантов масса.

От

```
void FillArray(int cnt, double *arr, double a = 0, double b = 1, double c = 2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i+=3) {
        arr[i] = a;
        if (i+1 < cnt) arr[i + 1] = b;
        if (i+2 < cnt) arr[i + 2] = c;
    }
}
```

до

```
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; ++i) 
{
    arr[i] == (i%3==0) ? a : (i%3 == 1) b : c;
}
```

P.S. Ага, раз пошла такая пьянка, пора достать алгебраический огурец:

```
void fillArray(int cnt, double *arr, double a = 0, double b = 1, double c = 2)
{
    double aa = (c+a)/2-b, bb = 2*b-(3*a+c)/2, cc = a;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        int j = i%3;
        arr[i] = (aa*j+bb)*j+cc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Вариантов можно несколько сделать, я бы сделал так:

```
void FillArray(int cnt, double *arr, double a = 0, double b = 1, double c = 2)
{
    double mas[] = {a, b, c};
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = mas[i % 3];
    }
}
```

Comment: Будьте внимательны к условию задачи...

Comment: А разве этот код делает не то, что запрошено в задаче? Внимательное чтение условия не помогло выявить несоответствие) Видимо я недостаточно внимателен...

Comment: Я не говорил, что  вы неправильно решили.  Просьба была исправлять то, как написано:  не нужен тут новый массив, но как вариант отмечу полезным...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, не соглашусь. В "Совершенный код" как раз рекомендуется заменять сложные условия типа `(i%3==0) ? a : (i%3 == 1) b : c` на массивы. Более того, этот код может оказаться более эффективным так как в нем нет ветвлений.

Answer (score 9):

Ну как же тут не вспомнить [нетленную классику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%94%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B0)? (Подразумевая `cnt > 0`)

```
void FillArray(int cnt, double *arr, double a = 0, double b = 1, double c = 2)
{
  int n = (cnt + 2) / 3;
  arr += cnt;

  switch (cnt % 3)
    do
    {
      case 0: *--arr = c;
      case 2: *--arr = b;
      case 1: *--arr = a;
    } while (--n > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Рекурсию в массы!

```
void FillArray(int cnt, double *arr, double a = 0, double b = 1, double c = 2, int idx = 0)
{
    if (idx == cnt) return;
    arr[idx] = a;
    FillArray(cnt, arr, b, c, a, idx + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

В ответах на этот вопрос слишком мало STL!

Думаю [`std::generate_n`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate_n/) отлично подойдет.

```
#include <algorithm>

void fillArray(int cnt, double *arr, double a = 0, double b = 1, double c = 2){
    std::generate_n(arr, cnt, [=]{
        static int i = 0; 
        static double values[] = {a, b, c}; 
        return values[i++ % std::size(values)];
    });
}
```

---

Или даже [`std::valarray`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/valarray/):

```
#include <valarray>

void fillArray(int cnt, double *arr, double a = 0, double b = 1, double c = 2){
    std::valarray<double> temp(cnt);
    auto slice = [cnt](int from, int step){ 
        return std::slice(from, (cnt - from + step - 1) / step, step);
    };

    temp[slice(0, 3)] = a;
    temp[slice(1, 3)] = b;
    temp[slice(2, 3)] = c;

    std::copy(std::begin(temp), std::end(temp), arr);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Я бы вынес условия из цикла, понятно, что по факту на большинстве современных архитектур это ускорения почти наверняка не даст, да  компилятор может догадаться сделать сам, но всё же...

```
void FillArray(int cnt, double *arr, double a = 0, double b = 1, double c = 2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < cnt-2; i+=3) {
        arr[i] = a;
        arr[i + 1] = b;
        arr[i + 2] = c;
    }

    if (i == cnt-2) {
        arr[i] = a;
        arr[i + 1] = b;
    } else if (i == cnt-1) {
        arr[i] = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: а я бы  сократил цикл в 3 раза

Comment: @ARHovsepyan и как же?

Comment: ок, напишу ответ